# static variables reinitializing themselves when moving from one activity to other

Tags: java, android, static-variables

I am using a public class name Constants in which I have static variables.

```
/*
 * Flags
 */
public static boolean gotCourse = false;
public static boolean quizTaken = false;
```

I am changing these flags in 1st activity and moving to 2nd (I also exit 1st Activity) but in 2nd activity I am getting the initial value of flags not the changed value. Why I am getting this problem?? Is there any limit of static variables for an app?

And I also don't want to pass these values through intent because they will complicate my logic.

Code of 1st Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_moviewrapper);
        Constants.quizTaken = extra.getBoolean("fromquiz", false);
        Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Got Course Value: "+Constants.gotCourse);
        if(Constants.gotCourse == false){
            mGetDataTask = new GetDataTask();
            mGetDataTask.execute();
            Constants.gotCourse = true;
        }else{
            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"In Play");
            playProgram();
        }
        Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Got Course Value: "+Constants.gotCourse);

    }
```

in which I am changing `Constants.gotCourse = true;`

Code of 2nd Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Got Course Value in Video Wrapper: "+Constants.gotCourse);
    }
```

Code of Task:

```
private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MovieWrapperActivity.this);

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {
        getCourse();
        return null;
    }

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
            playProgram();
        }
    }
}
```

ProgramPlay Function:

```
private void playProgram(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MovieWrapperActivity.this, VideoWrapperActivity.class);

        int chap_played = extra.getInt("chapterplayed",-1);
        Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Played: "+chap_played +" : chapter: "+Constants.mCourse.getTotalChapters());
        if(chap_played == -1){
            //Play 1st Chapter
            intent.putExtra("chaptertoplay", 1);
            //Chapter cha = mCourse.getmChapters().get(1);
            intent.putExtra("videofile",  Constants.mCourse.getmChapters().get(0).getVideoURL());
            if(Constants.mCourse.getmChapters().get(0).isQuiz()){
                Constants.quizTaken = false;
            }else{
                Constants.quizTaken = true;
            }
        }
        else if (chap_played < Constants.mCourse.getmChapters().size()){
            // For Playing 2nd to till last
            if(Constants.mCourse.getmChapters().get(chap_played-1).isQuiz() && !Constants.quizTaken){

                Intent in2 = new Intent(MovieWrapperActivity.this, QuestionWrapper.class);
                in2.putExtra("chaptertoplay", chap_played);
                Constants.quizTaken = true;
                startActivity(in2);
                //System.exit(0);

            }else{
                if(Constants.mCourse.getmChapters().get(chap_played).isQuiz()){
                    Constants.quizTaken = false;
                }else{
                    Constants.quizTaken = true;
                }
                intent.putExtra("videofile",  Constants.mCourse.getmChapters().get(chap_played).getVideoURL());
                intent.putExtra("chaptertoplay", chap_played+1);
            }

        }
        else if(chap_played == Constants.mCourse.getmChapters().size()){
            // Move to End Knowlege Test Here
            MovieWrapperActivity.this.finish();
        }
        Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Here...");
        startActivity(intent);
        System.exit(0);

    }
```

**Edit:** One more thing. When I am not finishing 1st activity and start 2nd activity I am getting changed value in 2nd activity.

**Update:** The Problem Occurs when I finish Activity with `System.exit(0);` but no problem when finish by `finish();`. But when finish activity with `finish();` It cause more runtime errors.

Comment: There is not enough code to answer your question, probably the mistake lays elsewhere.

Comment: here it seems no error ,give the full code ,once you changed the value of static variable so all the object and variable will get the changed value

Comment: I am not chaning value any where else...

Comment: When I am not finishing 1st activity and starting 2nd activity I am getting changed value in 2nd activity. the problem i got when finish 1st activity.

Comment: what is the execute() method doing?

Comment: @user_CC just fetching data from server.

Comment: does it also launches the 2nd activity?

Comment: @user_CC nop. Letme Add the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should extract these values into a shared resource class, with getters and setters. That way, their content may be retrieved anywhere.

Comment: I never used shared resource class type of thing. please can you provide some example. I am unable to find on google.

Answer (score 0):

It is because there are two different threads . Now in this case the 2nd Activity launches before the gotCourse variable is changed to true. So if you do something like below it will solve your problem.

```
 if(Constants.gotCourse == false){
         Constants.gotCourse = true;
        mGetDataTask = new GetDataTask();
        mGetDataTask.execute();

    }else{
```

Comment: where are you finishing the activity?

Comment: `playProgram` function of my activity which is called in `onPostExecute` of my `AsyncTask` code of `playProgram` added in Question.

Comment: I am not really convinced it is not working.... did you changed the variable before executing the GetDataTask()? If yes please can you try placing a Thread.sleep() before executing the task and see if it works..

Comment: @AhmedNawaz did you manage to solve this problem...it would be interesting to know the solution?

Comment: Ues Solved the problem. Now I am not finishing the Base Activity and opening the child activities by calling `startActivityForResult` . Actualy System.exit(0) was the reason of this problem..